# What exactly is a 'port', and how is it related to the internet?

Tags: web, network-programming, port

I've searched extensively on this topic, yet I'm still confused about what exactly a 'port' is.

I know what it is 'conceptually', and I know that there are many different ports, and that some numbers, like 80 are reserved for certain uses, and I know that by typing in the 'netstat' commands in the CMD I can check if they are in use.

But I still don't understand what a port is. Does it 'physically' exist on my computer? Because all I see is one Ethernet connection line that I plug in, not some 6000 different ports that do different things.

And I don't really get how it's got to do with my internet browser. When I click on my 'Chrome.exe.' icon, does that 'open' the 80 -number port?

Comment: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc793

Answer (score 10):

To reach a service on any networked computer you need to know 3 parameters. Some of them you provide explicitly and some of them are deduced by operating system implicitly. The three parameters are `IP Address`, `Protocol`, `Port number`. So any running service can be uniquely described by a combination of these three numbers.

Imagine, that we did not use port numbers. That would mean that on each computer we could have only one service using any of the protocols. So a web server could only serve HTTP protocol, mail server could only provide SMTP services and so on.

Usage of ports allows us to multiplex services on same computer. A port number is nothing more than a number, indicating what service should get a data packet. So we can have HTTP server, SMTP server and SSH server all running on a same computer and all using same protocol - namely TCP.

Also, these ports have nothing to do with a physical ports you see on your computer. Once again - they are just a number, allowing to distinguish which service (i.e. program) should receive which packet.

For example when I enter www.stackoverflow.com in my web-browsers address bar, my OS sends a HTTP request to `{IP:104.16.34.249, Proto: TCP, Port: 80}`. How does it know these numbers? IP address is resolved from the host name using the DNS protocol. Web browser is running HTTP protocol, which is using TCP. Port 80 is default port for HTTP. Behind the scenes, each packet will have destination address IP set to the above value and TCP payload will have destination port set to 80. On the SO computer, there will be a web-server running, which is listening for data received on port 80 and replies to my packet.

Answer (score 2):

A port number is a 16-bit unsigned integer, thus ranging from 0 to 65535. For TCP, port number 0 is reserved and cannot be used, while for UDP, the source port is optional and a value of zero means no port.

A process associates its input or output channels via an Internet socket, which is a type of file descriptor, associated with a transport protocol, an IP address, and a port number. This is known as binding.

A socket is used by a process to send and receive data via the network. The operating system's networking software has the task of transmitting outgoing data from all application ports onto the network, and forwarding arriving network packets to processes by matching the packet's IP address and port number to a socket. For TCP, only one process may bind to a specific IP address and port combination.

**Common application failures, sometimes called port conflicts, occur when multiple programs attempt to use the same port number on the same IP address with the same protocol.**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_(computer_networking)

Answer (score 1):

For short, ports are just logical numbers (not exists physically) related to services (or server software) whats are running above the operating system (ftp server, web server etc). When there is an incoming connection (or any traffic) addressed to a specific port, the OS can forward the traffic to the proper service for handling.

By default browsers are addressing the given site with port number 80 so
http://www.randomsite.com and http://www.randomsite.com:80 are identical.

Answer (score 0):

If you request something from the internet then it has to send data to your request but the data is been sent in the form of data packets and the server needs some address to where it has to send the data packets and here comes the role of IP address.
An IP address identifies a machine in an IP network and is used to determine the destination of a data packet.

So the data will reach to your system or computer but still it doesn't know which application it has to send the data so here we use port number to identify the applications.
**Port numbers identify a particular application or service on a system.**